# Build variables not accessible in my react native app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to inject env variables into my code.
I'm using azure pipelines to build my android app in react native. 
I have set env variables in the build configuration and I have created a file called appcenter-post-clone.sh. The contents of this file are as follows:

```
ENV ADMIN_HOST= $ADMIN_HOST
```

And in my build configuration I have defined 
`ADMIN_HOST = https://example.com`.

But I'm getting this error, `[command]/bin/bash /Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/1/s/appcenter-post-clone.sh
ENV: https://example.com: No such file or directory`. What I fail to understand here is, why is azure treating the value of my env variables as a file? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blunder I made here is, I should have used

```
ENV ADMIN_HOST=$ADMIN_HOST
```

Without the space. That solved it for me.